# Visual studio Database Project: Include If Exists checks for all the objects in the project

Tags: database-project

I have imported my database into a database project and so far everything looks good.

I would like to know if there is any way by which I can remove the suffix of the objects.

For example:
every table file has name as `SomeTable.table.sql`
and every procedure is named as `SomeProcedure.proc.sql`.
I want the file names to follow simple naming convention as `SomeObject.sql`.

Also, all the objects in the project have just Create statement.
I want to update the same into IF EXISTS statement like:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SomeTableName')
    AND type in (N'U')
    )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE SomeTableName
END
GO

CREATE TABLE SomeTableName...
```

I tried searching a lot of this on web, but couldn't find anything useful or any perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware it's not possible to configure the naming of the imported object files.
However, at least in the most recent incarnation of the database project, you should be able to rename them yourself after the import, and you can additionally organize your files in folders as you see fit.

It isn't possible to store the object definition files using `if exists` simply because this isn't their purpose. They are there to represent the objects, allowing you to view in your source control system how the objects have evolved over time. These scripts are not designed to be executed.

If you want to deploy from a database project you need to use the `Publish` feature, or use `Schema Compare`. This generates a difference script that *is* designed to be run.

Comment: Hi in cntinuation of the above response, While I try to deploy the Database Project by giving a different name in the target database (deploy properties), it the objects (SPs, Triggers, etc) if contain a reference to the earlier imported database say 'DBName' such way as in 
select * from DBName..TableName
 The deployed database with a different name still has the SPs referring to the original database. How to control this. When I deploy the database with a new name using Database Project, the objects shall now refer to the new Database and not the original database.